# How can a boys mass equal more than a seesaw plank when it is balanced?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I had a question that says a boy plays solitary seesaw by placing a long plank over a small rock and sitting at one end of the plank. When the seesaw is balanced the boys mass is likely… the answer is greater than the mass of the seesaw. I don’t understand how it could be greater. I understand the concept of how to get a balanced seesaw using distance from the center of gravity but what I don’t understand is why his mass is more.

Comment: Did a diagram or sketch come with the question?  Knowing the ratio of the plank that is on one side vs the other would give a good estimate of the ratio of the boy's mass to that of the plank.

Comment: No there was no other information along with the question.

Comment: If the pivot is in ceneter of the plank, you cannot balance it no matter what the boy's weight is. If you can pick up the pivot point arbitrarily, you can balance it with either the boy weighting more or less than the plank. Or even if it weights the same as the plank. So, it may be that you are missing some part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since torque is $\text{weight}\times \text{distance}$ we can write $$W_b\times l=W_p\times L$$ would be the condition when the seesaw is balanced, and $W_b$ is the weight of part of the plank and boy on one side, and $W_p$ is the weight of the plank on the other side, and $l$ and $L$ are the lengths of the plank from the pivot on each side similarly.

We can write the equation above $$m_bgl=m_pgL$$ Now for the seesaw to balance, there must be more plank length, and therefore more weight, on the opposite side without the boy for the possibility of equilibrium. So if we write $$\frac{m_b}{m_p}=\frac{L}{l}$$ and as discussed, $L\gt l$ meaning $\frac Ll \gt 1$ which means $$m_b\gt m_p$$

Comment: For the torque of the plank in respect to the pivot, you assume the whole weight of the plank acts at the free end of the plank? How do you justify this?

Comment: @nasu  I've edited it to make it more simple without the use of approximations. Thanks.

Comment: So, what is the torque produced by the weight of the plank? How can it be WpXL when L is the distance between the end of the plank and the pivot? The weight of the plank is distributed over the whole length of the plank, is not just at one end.

Comment: Yes, but we can agree that a greater mass of plank must be on the opposite side.

Comment: Yes, but this is not what the question is about.